# Cockpit fails to start socket

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, cockpit

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server
I installed cockpit using "sudo apt install cockpit" and had no errors.
I run "sudo systemctl status cockpit.socket" and recieve following error message:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHAU8.png)
I reboot and try "sudo systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket" and recieve following error message:
"Job failed. See "journalctl -xe" for details."
So I run "journalctl -xe" and get following error messages:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IADlm.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojvrT.png)

It made 7 sessions ID's if that is of any relevance.

Please help! I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Paste in question text, not images!

Comment: you deleted question [PlayerDB API Post Requests bring 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557817/playerdb-api-post-requests-bring-404) but you could describe solution as answer - it could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configure this software to listen to port 9090. And the error (image2) say this port is already in use. So check what is the software which listen on this port and stop it. Or change the port in `cockpit` config.